# Python compare last n characters of column and replace by longer version in same column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I've a rather complicated case here.

I have two columns, `ColumnA` showing groups and `ColumnB` the belonging numbers. Yet, the numbers in `ColumnB` aren't formatted in the same way, but they should look as in the desired output table below.

So for every group in `ColumnA` (e.g. `"1"`), the last 8 characters of `ColumnB` shall be compared to each other, and if they match, the longer one should be used in all rows of this group (in this case: `+495833934867348`). If there are numbers starting with `"49"` but without a `"+"`, a `"+"` should be added in front. If the number does not start with `"49"` and its last 8 characters does not match any other number in the same `ColumnA`-group, then it should stay the same (as the number starting with `8723...`).

```
| ColumnA | ColumnB         |
| --------| --------------  |
| 1       | +495833934867348|
| 1       | 05833934867348  |
| 2       | 0459345723462   |
| 2       | 459345723462    |
| 2       | +49459345723462 |
| 2       | 87234986239823  |
| 3       | 4923412454334   |
| 3       | 023412454334    |
| 3       | 492489303948239 |
```

So the desired output would be:

```
| ColumnA | ColumnB         |
| ------- | --------------  |
| 1       | +495833934867348|
| 1       | +495833934867348|
| 2       | +49459345723462 |
| 2       | +49459345723462 |
| 2       | +49459345723462 |
| 2       | 87234986239823  |
| 3       | +4923412454334  |
| 3       | +4923412454334  |
| 3       | +492489303948239|
```

Until now, I've managed to achieve smaller parts of this task, but not the connection between them.

With

```
df['ColumnB'].str[-8:]
```

I extract the 8 last characters of `ColumnB`.

With

```
pd.np.where(df['ColumnB'].astype(str).str.startswith('49') == True,
                                           "+" + df['ColumnB'],
                                           df['ColumnB'])
```

I put a `"+"` in front of every number startin with `"49"`.

But I don't know how to compare the extracted characters within the same group.
Every hint is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the `'+'` at the beginning of numbers with:

```
df['ColumnB'] = df['ColumnB'].apply(lambda x: '+' + x if x.startswith('49') else x)
```

Then you can compare the last 8 digits of each number and replace the shortest with the longest if they match by using:

```
for group in df['ColumnA'].unique():
    numbers = df[df['ColumnA'] == group]['ColumnB'].values
    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        for j in range(len(numbers)):
            if i != j:
                if numbers[i][-8:] == numbers[j][-8:]:
                    if len(numbers[i]) > len(numbers[j]):
                        numbers[j] = numbers[i]
                    else:
                        numbers[i] = numbers[j]
    df.loc[df['ColumnA'] == group, 'ColumnB'] = numbers
```

Result:

```
  ColumnA           ColumnB
0       1  +495833934867348
1       1  +495833934867348
2       2   +49459345723462
3       2   +49459345723462
4       2   +49459345723462
5       2    87234986239823
6       3    +4923412454334
7       3    +4923412454334
8       3  +492489303948239
```

Comment: Thank you, but I get the error: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'to_list'

Comment: I updated my answer: I replaced `.to_list()` method with `.values`, now it should work properly

Answer (score 2):

IIUC you can `groupby` on both ColumnA and last 8 digits of ColumnB, and then `transform`:

```
s = df.groupby(["ColumnA", df["ColumnB"].str[-8:]])["ColumnB"].transform(
    lambda d: d.sort_values(key=lambda d: d.str.len(), ascending=False).iat[0])

print (s.mask(s.str.startswith("49"), "+"+s))

0    +495833934867348
1    +495833934867348
2     +49459345723462
3     +49459345723462
4     +49459345723462
5      87234986239823
6      +4923412454334
7      +4923412454334
8    +492489303948239
Name: ColumnB, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you, but I get the Error: TypeError: sort_values() got an unexpected keyword argument 'key'

Comment: Means you are using an older version of `pandas`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - unfortunately I can't test this solution at my workplace (updating is blocked for security reasons), but I will test it at my private computer

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to achieve is applying some custom logic to a group of rows sharing a key (that is in ColumnA). The concept you're looking for is grouping.
There are a few ways to go about it:

1. The groupby-apply technique, which groups your rows given a key and applies
   some logic to them.
2. Iterating over unique values of your ColumnA values, subselecting your group via the loc operator and applying your logic. This may be faster in some cases where you have a large number of groups compared to your number of rows.

   ```
   # Group by apply
   def my_logic_for_a_group(group):
      pass

   df.groupby('ColumnA').apply(my_logic_for_a_group)

   # loc method
   for key in df['ColumnA'].unique():
     group = df[df['ColumnA'] == key]
     # logic here
     df.loc[df['ColumnA'] == key, 'ColumnB'] = my_processed_column_b
   ```

Both of these methods may not be as performant as arriving at a fully vectorized implementation of your logic (as I think you were trying to do), but given your data is not too large will perform reasonably and be very straight forward to implement.